# How do i set and get session attributes in ejb

Tags: java, jsp, session, ejb

I have created a loginservlet that maps to the userbean now i am unable to set the session attributes and get it in the jsp page. Please advice me on how to overcome this problem.

```
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
        throws ServletException, IOException {
    processRequest(request, response);

    String username = request.getParameter("Username");
    String password = request.getParameter("Password");

    PrintWriter pw = response.getWriter();
  //  pw.println("Username: " + username);
  //  pw.println("Password: " + password);
    //String CurrentUsername=(String)session.setAttribute("Username");
   // HttpSession session = request.getSession();
 //   String currentusername = (String)request.getAttribute(username);
    //session.setAttribute("CurrentUser", username);
    if (userBean.login(username, password)) 
      //  pw.println("Login Successful");

    response.sendRedirect("my-account.jsp?username="+username);
    else 
        pw.println("Login Failed");

}
```

This is the loginservlet i have been trying it and i have commented all the methods iv tried. I should be able to retrieve other data like password also through that session attribute. Please tell me a way to get the attribute on jsp page aswell. Thanks in advance.

```
 <%
        String CurrentUsername=(String)session.getAttribute("CurrentUser");
        request.setAttribute("CurrentUser",CurrentUsername );
       // session.getAttribute("CurrentUser");
       out.println(CurrentUsername);

        %>
```

This is what i tried in jsp page

Comment: <%
            String CurrentUsername=(String)session.getAttribute("CurrentUser");
            request.setAttribute("CurrentUser",CurrentUsername );
           // session.getAttribute("CurrentUser");
           out.println(CurrentUsername);
      
            %>

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you forgot to set the session attribute in the page directive.

```
<%@ page session="true" %>
```

Since you didn't post the whole JSP, but only the scriplet, I can't be sure.
Also I don't think this problem has anything to do with EJBs.

Comment: So are you trying to say that all what i have commented is correct?

Comment: NO. The code doesn't make sense: you use both a Servlet and a JSP for credentials check while one of them would be enough. Furthermore you set both session and request attributes (?!). My answer was about the use of the session built-in object.